# toString and uiString error: app is not giving a recommendations

Tags: javascript, stem, code.org

I am making an app that is used to give the user a recommended element after they input what they are looking for, within the element. Everything is working, besides the recommendations at the end. The box stays empty and these two errors appear. I’ll link my app below.

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/rTKOvTc9QDnXk15TEmKHq_XUjV15j3FraK2Kx9liP-k

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the question? As you may think, what is wrong with your example?

Comment: Yes! My question is on what the error in line 64 is when the app is ran. It asks “ settext() text parameter value ( undefined ) is not a uistring. typeerror: Cannot read property “toString” of undefined. I don’t know what that error means, nothing in my program is labeled “ tostring” or “uiString”. I would like to know what the error means and how to fix it